# Ruby Rails callback URL in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, portforwarding

I am integrating Plivo in to my application(Ruby/Rails) and I would like to setup the router to point to my local dev environment for the callback. I have setup my controller method: plivo/receive_sms and the associated route in routes.rb

My question is: How do I setup my router(NETGEAR) to receive the callback for localhost:3000/plivo/receive_sms from Plivo?

I have tried forwarding port 80 to my local IP (192.168.1.20) But that did not work.. So I added ports 3000 - 8080 with no success.

Comment: Have you set up the correct callback address in Plivo? Depending on your ISP, your public IP address may change periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

1. Make sure you are forwarding external port 80 to your local port 3000.
2. Make sure the Plivo is configured with your OUTGOING public IP address as the call back URL hostname. (google for "What is my ip"? and google will tell you)
3. If that doesn't work, perhaps your computer is firewalled? Or your router / ISP firewalls port 80?
4. If #3 is the case, then try forwarding port 3000 to your local port 3000, but then you have to be able to change the callback URL (#2) to use port 3000.

Or - try:

- localtunnel.me
- localtunnel gem
- PageKite
- ShowOff
- https://pagekite.net/2011-04-20/PageKite_meets_Showoff
- http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/04/27/http-forwarding-services-for-local-facebook-development/

Or if you have access to a server thats sits somewhere on the internet, there are gems similar to local tunnel that will use your own server to do the proxying.

Or you can do it manually with SSH using the -R or -L option (I forget which).